# C segmentation fault when passing a NULL pointer despite a conditional telling the function not to run if a NULL parameter is passed?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I have a program which handles an array of strings. One of the methods removes a string from a specified position in said array. The code is as follows:

```
void RemoveStringAt(char *array[], int pos)
{
    if((array[pos]!=NULL)&&(array!=NULL)&&(pos!=NULL))
    {
        free(array[pos]);
        array[pos]=NULL;
    }
}
```

One of the specifications of the project was that it should not cause a seg fault when passing a NULL value. Here's what happened when I tried:

```
 RemoveStringAt(NULL, NULL);
```

And the output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why would I be getting a segmentation fault if one of the conditions for even executing the core part of the method is that none of the values passed can be NULL?

Comment: You have the checks in the wrong order. `array[pos]` is causing the seg fault before the check for `array != NULL` can run.

Comment: `pos != NULL` is a semantic mistake; `pos` is an integer. If you meant `pos != 0` then write that

Comment: Are you afraid of spaces? `if (array && pos != 0 && array[pos])` is much clearer. No need to compare a pointer with NULL

Comment: This test `NULL != array[pos]` is redundant, as `free()` accepts `NULL`.

Comment: Also `int` shall better be `size_t`, the perferred type to index array. Also there is  no need for negative values here.

Answer (score 15):

Because you are dereferencing a NULL pointer as part of the check:

```
if((array[pos]!=NULL)...
```

`array` is NULL so you cannot do `array[pos]`. In C the `if` condition evaluates from left to right so just change your conditional to be like the below. That is, change the ordering so that `array[pos]` is never evaluated if `array` is NULL.

```
if((array!=NULL) && (pos < MAX_POS) && (array[pos]!=NULL))
```

Note that your original check `pos!=NULL` is not correct. For serveral reasons. 1. `pos` is not a pointer so comparing it against `NULL` is not semantically correct. 2. `NULL` is usually defined to be `0` and `0` is a valid `pos` value. So you need to either define a `MAX_POS` specifying the number of entries in `array` or better still, pass that in as an explicit parameter to the function.

And finally, after all that, you don't actually even have to have the `array[pos]!=NULL` check in the conditional if you don't want to. Nothing inside the `if` block will cause a segv even if `array[pos]` is `NULL` as `free` is defined to accept a `NULL` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with

```
if((array[pos]!=NULL)&&(array!=NULL)&&(pos!=NULL))
```

First

```
if((array[pos]!=NULL)
```

will be checked and if the array is `NULL` it will give a segmentation fault. After this condition

```
(array!=NULL)&&(pos!=NULL))
```

will be checked.

Your code should be like

```
void RemoveStringAt(char *array[], int pos)
{
    if((array!=NULL)&& (array[pos]!=NULL))
    {
        free(array[pos]);
        array[pos]=NULL;
    }
}
```

And there should not be `NULL` check for `pos` because `NULL` is defined to be `0` and `0` is a valid index in array so we should be able to free at `0` index.

Comment: `pos!=NULL` does not make sense.

Comment: @ask yes what i have wrote in my last line. 0 is acceptable for index in array.

Comment: So why didn't you remove it from you example code, please, as the "*code should [not] be like [this]*".

Answer (score 0):

The best effort solution on input validation would look like this:

```
void RemoveStringAt(char *array[], int pos)
{
  if (NULL != array) && (0 <= pos))
  {
    free(array[pos]);
    array[pos]=NULL;
  }
}
```

The validation shown still may no prevent the call from failing if `pos` accesses `array` out of bounds. This simply is not possible with the minimal interface given.

Comment: It's so interesting how you do `(NULL != array)` and the same for `pos` instead of `(array != NULL)`. Might be first time I've seen that.

Comment: @RastaJedi: This is called using "*Yoda-Conditions*" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).